# What's the correct way to trigger jQuery DOM Manipulation from within a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

So I keep reading that jQuery manipulation from within a Controller is bad practice, but I'm not clear on why, or how to correct.

Below is code from a Youtube tutorial which even the video creator comments is a bad idea, but doesn't explain why and continues to use the bad behavior anyway.

From https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilCH2Euobz0#t=553s :

```
$scope.delete = function() {
    var id = this.todo.Id;
    Todo.delete({id: id}, function() {
        $('todo_' + id).fadeOut();
    });
};
```

*SOLUTION*:

Based on Langdon's answer below, I've arrived at the following working code for my own work, which derives slightly from the example code above:

```
var ProjectListCtrl = function ($scope, Project) {
    $scope.projects = Project.query();
    $scope.delete = function() {
        var thisElem = this;
        var thisProject = thisElem.project;
        var id = thisProject.id;
        Project.delete({id: id}, function() {
            var idx = $scope.projects.indexOf(thisProject);
            if (idx !== -1) {
                thisElem.destroy('removeItem('+idx+')');
            }
        });
    }

    $scope.removeItem = function(idx) {
        $scope.projects.splice(idx, 1);
    }

}

app.directive('fadeOnDestroy', function() {
    return function(scope, elem) {
        scope.destroy = function(funcComplete) {
            elem.fadeOut({
                complete: function() {
                    scope.$apply(funcComplete)
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This differs from Langdon's answer in a few ways. I wanted to avoid adding a parameter to the `ngClick` callback, so I'm storing it in `thisProject`. Also, the example and my code needs to call `destroy` from within a `$http` success callback so instead of `this` which is no longer relevant, I'm storing the clicked element in `thisElem`.

**UPDATE 2**:

Updated my solution further to reflect that funcComplete was not actually modifying the original $scope.

Comment: There's no correct way to do DOM manipulations in Angular Controllers. This is what directives are for. See [How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/1095616).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Angular way to handle this is through a directive.  I found a perfect example to cover what you're asking below, although it's not as clean as I'd like.  The idea is that you create a directive to be used as an HTML attribute.  When the element gets bound to the scope of your controller, the `link` function is fired.  The function fades the element in (totally optional) and exposes a destroy method for your controller to call later.

Update: Modified based on comments to actually affect the scope.  Not thrilled with the solution, and it's even jankier because the original author called `complete.apply(scope)` in his destroy callback, but doesn't use `this` inside the callback function.

Update 2: Since the directive is the one making the callback asynchronous, it's probably a better idea to use `scope.$apply` there, but keep in mind that that might get weird if you ever use isolated scope in your directive.

**http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/K4Kx8/114/**

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items" fadey="500">
          {{item}}
          <a ng-click="clearItem(item)">X</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <hr />
  <button ng-click="items.push(items.length)">Add Item</button>    
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [0, 1, 2];

    $scope.clearItem = function(item) {
        var idx = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
        if (idx !== -1) {
            //injected into repeater scope by fadey directive
            this.destroy(function() {
                $scope.items.splice(idx, 1);
            });
        }
    };
}

myApp.directive('fadey', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // restricts the use of the directive (use it as an attribute)
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) { // fires when the element is created and is linked to the scope of the parent controller
            var duration = parseInt(attrs.fadey);
            if (isNaN(duration)) {
                duration = 500;
            }
            elm = jQuery(elm);
            elm.hide();
            elm.fadeIn(duration)

            scope.destroy = function(complete) {
                elm.fadeOut(duration, function() {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        complete.$apply(scope);
                    });
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

As for why, I think it's simply for separation of concerns and perhaps usability.  Your controller should be concerned with data flow and business logic, not interface manipulation.  You directives should ideally be written for usability (as in the case of `fadey` here -- ed. note: I wouldn't call it fadey ;)).

Comment: if using jQuery, include it before angular.js so that angular then adopts the full jQuery library instead of it's own **[jQlite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element)**. By doing this, `elm` in directive is a jQuery object already and don't have to wrap it in `jQuery(elm)`   http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/2222/

Comment: I use console.log(this) on line 10 http://jsfiddle.net/K4Kx8/112/
it says this is a 'Child' object. why? what is this class?

Comment: This all seems to work fine, however my original example includes an Object.delete success callback, within which `this` no longer refers to the element clicked, so I'm not sure what object I need to call `destroy()` on ? (also, apologies, I accepted the answer prematurely, until I realized it doesn't seem to cover the example above)

Comment: Ok figured it out, I'll post my exact solution and accept this. Thanks!

Comment: @AladdinHoms In this case, I believe it's the scope that exists inside the ng-repeat (where the item # and the destroy function are provided).

Comment: there's a bit of a problem here actually, it seems the splicing doesn't affect the original $scope of the Controller. If I omit the `remove()` from my answer as you have, the LI still exists in the DOM albeit hidden by the `fadeOut()`. As a result, an "empty" row such as `<li ng-hide="items.length">No items</li>` fails to trigger since `items` continues to have length despite the splice.

Comment: Good catch!  A simple fix is to wrap the splice in `$scope.$apply`, further convoluting the solution.  I've updated the answer above.

Comment: I've updated my solution, I went for a solution more in line with this: http://egghead.io/video/rough-draft-angularjs-directives-talking-to-contro/

Answer (score 0):

The code showed in this post was very helpful for me to understand the relationship controller - directive, but it was throwing a js error.

```
TypeError: Object function (scope) {
  $scope.items.splice(idx, 1);
  console.log($scope.items)
} has no method '$apply'
```

I have updated the directive slightly, and now it works to me:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    $scope.clearItem = function(item) {
        var idx = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
        if (idx !== -1) {
            //injected into repeater scope by fadey directive
            this.destroy(function(scope) {

                $scope.items.splice(idx, 1);

                //this now shows the expected results
                console.log($scope.items)
            });
        }
    };
}

myApp.directive('fadey', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // restricts the use of the directive (use it as an attribute)
        // fires when the element is created and is linked to the scope of the parent controller
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) { 
            var duration = parseInt(attrs.fadey);
            if (isNaN(duration)) {
                duration = 500;
            }
            elm = jQuery(elm);
            elm.hide();
            elm.fadeIn(duration)

            scope.destroy = function(complete) {
                elm.fadeOut(duration, function() {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        //note the change here 
                        complete(scope);
                    });
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```