# AngularJS manipulate DOM with JQuery after HTML rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I try to run JQuery after dom rendering.
Here is the code:

```js
angular.module('testCtrl', ['testService'])

.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'Test', function($scope,$timeout, Test) {
    var vm = this;
        Test.getFromServer().success(function(data) {
            vm.result = data;
            vm.processing = false;
     });
}]);
```

```html
<test ng-controller="testController as test" >
<note id="note">{{test.result}}</note>
```

The "getFromServer" function is an asynchronous call to the server that retrieve some HTML.

I want to manipulate this html with JQuery.

What should I use ? directive ? $watch ? $broadcast ?

Could you please give me a running example ?

Comment: What did you try? What "manipulation" do you want to do?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744630/whats-the-correct-way-to-trigger-jquery-dom-manipulation-from-within-a-controll

Comment: I need to parse the html with jquery to update some tags

Answer (score 0):

It is standard to manipulate the DOM in directives only. What you could do is write the whole thing as a directive.

```js
function testDirective(Test){
   return {
     controller: 'testController as test',
     link: function(scope, attr, elem, test){
        Test.getFromServer().success(function(data) {
           test.result = data;
           test.processing = false;
        });
     }
   }
}
```

```html
<div test-directive>
    <note id="note">{{test.result}}</note>
</div>
```