# Showing modals: Angular directive/libraries VS direct native jQuery/bootstrap calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I’ve been searching for the best way to handle modals in angular and I'm getting the impression that they need to be separated from controllers in order to achieve separation of concerns in MVC.
However when it comes to implementing this using a directive or a library out there I don't see the need for such massive overhead of adding so much code. Effectively it seems as though we are doing exactly the same thing but with more calls and events kicking off as compared to directly showing a bootstrap modal in the controller or service using jQuery as easy as:

```
    $scope.saveChanges = function () {
        $('#messageTitle').text('Done');
        $('#messageText').text('Changes have been saved.');
        $('#message').modal()
    }
```

Porting a directive to handle the dialog is in effect showing the modal with additional steps and setups between dependencies etc. within angular, external libraries and/or custom code (whichever way it is applied). It's really like having a more simplified method call to a utilities method in some utils file that will just show the modal using jQuery. Again, I would be enlightened to know why this is not case which I expect from more experienced angular experts.

Apart from the fact that it is assumed a correct working way to do it, is there a reason why the DOM should not be referenced inside a controller. Could it have an effect on things like i.e. performance, buggy code, testing etc.?

I know that because it makes test cases easier is one of the reasons. Again, a valid reason however testing is not much of an issue having the DOM in business logic as in the code above if tested right. If there are, even more pressing cases for this, what are they? If any what is the best and most efficient way to achieve separation of the DOM from controllers/services if the same applies to services?

Background into current explanations:

[What's the correct way to trigger jQuery DOM Manipulation from within a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744630/whats-the-correct-way-to-trigger-jquery-dom-manipulation-from-within-a-controll)

[Separating DOM manipulation from Angular controllers - Best Practice wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988547/separating-dom-manipulation-from-angular-controllers-best-practice-wanted)

[AngularJS - why manipulating DOM in controller is a bad thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981419/angularjs-why-manipulating-dom-in-controller-is-a-bad-thing)

[Why is it considered a bad idea to manipulate DOM in controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032855/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-idea-to-manipulate-dom-in-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, these are the main reasons why a controller should not manipulate the DOM:

- Testing. Test cases or test steps can be made well-structured and very easily testable when testing logic in controllers. Here what is tested is truly what a controller should be responsible for (Model manipulation).
- Applying well-structured MVC code at the angular code base. Separation of concerns again gives a plus mark for testing but also makes code more manageable and well structured.

I would be happy to hear more detailed alternative answers to completely confirm and explain that any DOM manipulation what so ever is a bad thing within a controller. On the contrary it would be interesting to know whether there are exceptions. For the information of others and my attempt to answer, the reasons above are the most commonly known reasons and thus probably the only reasons to my knowledge, which fair enough are acceptable reasons at this point.